# Spring Boot - custom 404 page with standalone tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am running a Spring boot application inside a standalone tomcat instance, and I am trying to override the error pages. From my understanding, Spring provides a filter [ErrorPageFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/ErrorPageFilter.java) that allows me to just setup error pages as normal for Springs `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`  to handle this case exactly.

So I have my standard auto configuration/servlet initializer in one class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [ GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, SecurityAutoConfiguration, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, JmxAutoConfiguration ] )
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application ) {
        application.sources( Application )
    }
```

(I am using the same class for autoconfiguration and servlet init, which is why i just pass my `Application` class in the configure method)

Looking at the source code for [SpringBootServletInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.java) it looks like the `ErrorPageFilter` class is being added by just extending that class here.  I have turned off the `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` - but again, looking at that source code it looks like that is just setting default error pages and not actually setting anything up with the `ErrorPageFilter`.

I then have my error config file:

```
@Configuration
class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override public void customize( ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container ) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/errors/404" ))
    }
```

However, if I just visit an invalid URL, and I `DispatcherServlet` can't find a match then I just get tomcats /404.html - not my view linked to "`/errors/404`"  (I have this path mapped to a thymeleaf view template, that works fine - if I navigate to /errors/404 it displays ok)

Any ideas why my custom error page is not working?  tracing the logs, I get a line about the `ErrorPageFilter` being configured and setup ok on application startup, but then no mentions of the filter doing anything when a request comes in.

Comment: The example in the docs is with `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-configurableembeddedservletcontainerfactory-directly

Comment: Awesome - I have been searching the docs for days, not sure how I missed that!  Have I misunderstood the point of the ErrorPageFilter class then? The comments in the source code/javadoc really make it sound like the sole-purpose of that class is to allow custom error pages in standalone WAR deployments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following code for older versions of spring boot (0.5.x)

```
  public class ServerCustomization extends ServerProperties {

  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {

    super.customize(factory);
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            "/yourpath/error-not-found.jsp"));
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            "/yourpath/error-internal.jsp"));
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/yourpath/error-other.jsp"));
   }
}
```

Newer spring boot versions (1.X.RELEASE) has some refactoring around ServerProperties. See below,

```
  public class ServerCustomization extends ServerProperties {

  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

    super.customize(container);
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            "/jsp/404.jsp"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            "/jsp/500.jsp"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage("/jsp/error.jsp"));
  }

}
```

Then define a bean to inject ServerProperies.

```
@Bean
public ServerProperties getServerProperties() {
    return new ServerCustomization();
}
```

Sample project posted in [git](https://github.com/kamoor/spring-boot-sample)

> Very Important: If you are using maven to build, You must store all the resource files under src/main/resources folder. Otherwise maven will not add those files to final jar artifact.

Comment: I will probably go with Evgeni's answer in the comment above, but this looks like a good solution as well, so will mark this as accepted.

Comment: Ok, I spoke to soon - neither these solutions are making a difference.. any other ideas?

Comment: This answer is just as correct as your own attempt (`ServerProperties` is an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`), so it would be useful to have more information (like a complete project).

Answer (score 3):

You can either use Spring Boot's builtin error view by implementing a view named `error`, or switch it off by setting `error.whitelabel.enabled=false` property and implement your own. It's [explained more in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-whitelabel-error-page).