# Spring Boot get the browser request URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple rest controller which captures errors. I want to get the actual URL that the browser sent to server, but the servlet is giving me a different URL.

If I navigate to `127.0.0.1/abc` a 404 error is triggered, and it's routed to `/error` handler as defined. However, the output gives me the result `127.0.0.1/error` instead of `127.0.0.1/abc`. How can I obtain the original URL?

```
@RestController
public class IndexController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "OK";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("ERR: " + request.getRequestURL() + " : " + request.getRequestURI());
        return "ERR";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Comment: You might instead wish to create a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, and use the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation to catch the exception thrown by Spring Boot for the 404 and handle it that way. The following answer provides an example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510975/2535264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define your own `@ExceptionHandler` that will save the original request URI as an attribute on your request before it's handled by `/error` mapping:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public void handleException(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
  req.setAttribute("originalUri", req.getRequestURI());
  req.getRequestDispatcher("/error").forward(req, resp);
}
```

and then read the new `originalUri` attribute in whatever `/error` mapping implementation you are using:

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public String error(HttpServletRequest request) {
  System.out.println("ERR: " + request.getAttribute("originalUri"));
  return "ERR";
}
```

You can also try extending other error handling classes available in Spring MVC to add this behavior e.g. [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html). Please note that the `forward()` in my example might be considered superficial as it's ok to return the `ResponseEntity` from `@ExceptionHandler`.