# How do I log the request path for invalid 404 requests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I tried the following to log the request path but they are not giving the correct values. The request is not being redirected either.

```
@Controller
@ApiIgnore
public class AppController implements ErrorController{

  @RequestMapping("/error")
  public void invalidRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    CustomLogger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getHeader("path"));
    CustomLogger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getPathInfo());
    CustomLogger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getPathTranslated());
    CustomLogger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getContextPath());
    CustomLogger.error(TAG, "invalidRequest()", "invalid request: " + request.getServletPath());
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String getErrorPath() {
    return "/error";
  }
```

When I make the request, I get

```
$ curl -i localhost:8080/static/img/notthere.png
HTTP/1.1 200
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 27
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2018 23:13:30 GMT

This is not a valid request
```

And this is what's printed in the logs:

```
2018-11-07 18:13:30.967 ERROR 14432 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.apis.AppController  : invalid request: null
2018-11-07 18:13:30.968 ERROR 14432 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.apis.AppController  : invalid request: null
2018-11-07 18:13:30.968 ERROR 14432 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.apis.AppController  : invalid request: null
2018-11-07 18:13:30.969 ERROR 14432 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.apis.AppController  : invalid request:
2018-11-07 18:13:30.969 ERROR 14432 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.apis.AppController  : invalid request: /error
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777723/how-i-create-an-error-handler-404-500-in-spring-boot-mvc/38789106 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get actual uri by using `Request Dispatcher` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)

```
request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
```