# Using @ControllerAdvice annotation @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) is working but @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class) is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to return custom JSON responses in spring boot. Below is my code. `defaultExceptionHandler` gets called fine if there is an error in the application or spring boot service throws an exception. But `handleAuthenticationException` never gets called even if I enter bad credentials. In this case, default spring-boot response is returned. This service is security confi is setup to use basic auth.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class})
    public ServiceError handleAuthenticationException(final Exception ex) {
        //LOGGER.error(ex.toString(), ex);
        return new ServiceError(ServiceErrorCode.REQUEST_INVALID, ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ServiceError defaultExceptionHandler(final Exception ex) {
        //LOGGER.error(ex.toString(), ex);
        return new ServiceError(ServiceErrorCode.SERVICE_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Default response which is getting return instead of custom response:

```
   {
"timestamp": 16654436345,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Bad credentials",
"path": "/mycontroller"}
```

Securtiy config class:

```
    @Configuration
public static class ServiceWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
            csrf().
            disable().
            exceptionHandling().
        and().
            headers().
            frameOptions().
            disable().
        and().
            sessionManagement().
            sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
        and().
            authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/service/**").authenticated().
            antMatchers("/health").permitAll().
            antMatchers("/metrics").permitAll().
            antMatchers("/info").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN).
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how you set up your security config, which you didn't show, the 401 might be being triggered before the MVC dispatch happens. Turn up your logging to `DEBUG` and post the results.

Comment: Thank chrylis for suggestion. posting security config

Comment: _It appears_ the security code is sending back a `HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED` response - given the 401. Therefore, the expected exception is never thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC is based on servlet, and spring security is based on filter, filter is before servlet, so the exception handler in your controller will not be executed, because it's already failed in filter.

if you want to handler the `AuthenticationException`, you need to handle it to implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and override the `commence` method.

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
```

`http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(myEntryPoint());`

`AuthenticationException` and `AccessDeniedException` have already been handled by `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. You just need to inject `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandler`(which handle `AccessDeniedException`)

Comment: Curious as to why  this is not working in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510975/384554

Comment: The exception is in filter which is before servlet